# hibernate batch insert still generates many insert statements

Tags: hibernate

I have this hibernate code that inserts 2k objects. I have setup hibernate for batch processing of my inserts and the code and everything looks like the examples from hibernate site. I do see an improvement when batch processing is in effect but when I profile my application I actually see 2k insert statements are being sent to my database. I sort of expected insert statements to be less and in form of

`insert into table1(c1, c2) values (...), (...), ..., (...)`

Is this the wrong expectation or there is something wrong with my batch processing setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a wrong expectation. Batch updates simply means that instead of sending every insert statement separately to the database, they're [added to a batch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29), and once a given number has been added, the batch is sent to the database.

Comment: A little example article related to this: http://brian.pontarelli.com/2011/06/21/jdbc-batch-vs-multi-row-inserts/